# Quarkus - Resource with @Path("/") ignored, instead loading content from resources

Tags: quarkus

Trying to configure a JAX-RS resource with @Path("/"), however, the resource is ignored and the first file found in resources is loaded.

Any idea how to prevent this and allow the resource to work?
When clearing META-INF/resources, the JAX-RS resource loads correctly.

Using:
Quarkus 1.4.2.Final

openjdk version "11.0.6" 2020-01-14 LTS
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Zulu11.37+52-SA (build 11.0.6+10-LTS)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Zulu11.37+52-SA (build 11.0.6+10-LTS, mixed mode)

Resource:

```java
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("/")
public class LandingResource {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
    public String getLandingPage() {
        return "<html><head><title>Hello World</title></head><body>Hello!</body></html>";
    }

}
```

Testing:

```sh
curl --location --request GET 'http://localhost:8080/'
```

Response:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Internal Server Error - Error handling cee4cff3-551d-44e1-9102-5c9ada9d8fb2-7, java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal char &amp;lt;:&amp;gt; at index 97: <tempdir>\vertx-cache\file-cache-71fbfca9-5ba3-4a3e-8020-8501379cbf2b\<project dir>\src\main\resources\META-INF\resources\assets\icons\icon-128x128.png</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 100%;
    font-weight: 100;
    line-height: 1.4;
}
...
```

Answer (score 2):

Achieved the desired outcome by adding a vertx web route:

```java
import io.quarkus.vertx.web.Route;
import io.vertx.core.http.HttpMethod;
import io.vertx.ext.web.RoutingContext;

import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;

@ApplicationScoped
public class LandingRoute {

    @Route(path = "/", methods = HttpMethod.GET)
    public void landing(RoutingContext rc) {
        rc.response().end("hello ");
    }
}
```

In order to use @Route annotation you need to add quarkus-reactive-routes extension (`io.quarkus:quarkus-reactive-routes`) to project.

You can find more information about reactive routes in Quarkus documentation at:
https://quarkus.io/guides/reactive-routes

Answer (score 0):

By default Quarkus will serve static resources from the root context.
That means that the resources inside `src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/` are already mapped to root (*http://localhost:8080/*). This means that you can not map a standard JAX-RS on the root easily.

See the documentation for further information: https://quarkus.io/guides/http-reference

In your case you are returning a fixed HTML landing page. As a solution you could remove the LandingResource class and serve the landing page from the static resources.

This can be achieved by placing the HTML snippet in `src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/index.html`.

This is also how the default Quarkus default landing page is served.

Comment: Thank you Pieterjan.
The intention here, however, is to serve dynamic HTML on the root instead of a static HTML file.
When adding a index.html into the resources folder, it is served up as expected, however, we would like the root to provide a dynamic HTML file, whilst still able to serve static content from resources.

Comment: Ah, my answer is indeed targeted towards a static HTML file. But I see you already found a solution for the dynamic scenario as well :)

Answer (score 0):

To add on Pieterjan's answer, you can know (since version 2.16) use the dedicated application property for setting the index page of the static files

```
quarkus.http.static-resources.index-page
```

https://quarkus.io/guides/http-reference

Note: for me using quarkus-undertow dependency was blocking the property. So I had to remove it.